# Redirect to login.php if not logged in

Tags: php, authentication

I'm a beginner and need some help with my code.

If I enter the webpage **index.php**, I want to be redirected to **login.php** if I'm not logged in.

I'm using this code and it works so I redirects to **login.php**, but I can't log in. I'm stuck at **login.php**.

I have this code in my **index.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
        // comment
    } else {
        header("Location:login.php");
    }
?>
```

Parts of my login.php

```
<?php
include('template.php');
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pwd = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$query = <<<END
SELECT username, password, user_id FROM users4project
WHERE username = '{$name}'
AND password = '{$pwd}'
END;
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$row = $result->fetch_object();
$_SESSION["username"] = $row->username;
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $row->user_id;
header("Location:index.php");
} else {
echo "Wrong username or password. Try again";
}
}
$content = <<<END
                    <form action="login.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="username" required placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" name="password" required placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Remember Me</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                    </form>
END;
echo $navigation;
echo $content;
?>
```

my template.php

```
    session_name('Website');
    session_start();
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = " ";
    $pwd = " ";
    $db = " ";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
```

Comment: What is the issue with login.php?

Comment: when i click log in it just "resets" and loops. even if i use the right password and username i cant come in

Comment: try to post your `login.php` page

Comment: @enille then post the code of login.php file

Comment: @enille u must always add `session_start()` on top of everypage

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: what does <<<END do?

Comment: but i include template.php and it contains session_start()?

Answer (score 1):

```
isset($_SESSION['userId'] !== $_SESSION["user_id"]
```

aside from the major security issues, you're not comparing the right session name

(for clarity)
You check

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
        // comment
```

but you set

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ....
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row->user_id;
.....
```

PappaJ says "pick a naming convention, and stick with it"